# ESP8266 failure to connect to router

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to get a ESP8266 board with 2x4 pins to work. I'm connecting it to an Olimexino 32u4 (Leonardo-compatible), configured to use 3.3V. This simple snippet I use to transfer everything to the PC (CH_PD is connected to D8, /RST to D9):

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(2000);
  // initialize both serial ports:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  delay(10000);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  // read from port 1, send to port 0:
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial1.read();
    Serial.write(inByte);
  }

  // read from port 0, send to port 1:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial1.write(inByte);
  }
}
```

When launching, I see following output:

```
<"random" bytes>
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.

invalid
```

Performing a reset shows more:

```
AT+RST


OK

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x40100000, len 1396, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0x89
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 4 
tail 4
chksum 0xe8
load 0x3ffe8308, len 540, room 4 
tail 8
chksum 0xc0
csum 0xc0

2nd boot version : 1.4(b1)
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : QIO
  SPI Flash Size & Map: 8Mbit(512KB+512KB)
jump to run user1 @ 1000

ŒÂÕ�MEM CHECK FAIL!!!
äsl�‚rô
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.

invalid
```

The mode is set to station:

```
AT+CWMODE?

+CWMODE:1

OK
```

Listing the access points works fine:

```
AT+CWLAP

+CWLAP:(3,"ap-1",-91,"01:23:45:67:89:ab",1)
+CWLAP:(3,"ap-2",-88,"cd:ef:01:23:45:67",2)
+CWLAP:(3,"ap-3",-74,"89:ab:cd:ef:01:23",11)

OK
```

But logging in to my Fritzbox router fails (WPA2):

```
AT+CWJAP="ap-2","mypassword"
WIFI CONNECTED
+CWJAP:1

FAIL
WIFI DISCONNECT
```

First I thought the reason is the low signal, but even moving directly beside the Fritzbox shows the same result (though with higher signal value in `AT+CWLAP`).

I've tried nearly everything, e.g. `AT+CWMODE=3`, `AT+RST`, `AT+RESTORE`). Nothing changes. When using a wrong password, I'm getting no "WIFI CONNECTED" messages at all.

Could it be a power problem (that the Olimexino can't provide up to 200mA at the 3.3V line?

Connecting from my smartphone to the ESP8266 in one of its access point modes (2 or 3) works fine. If there were power problems, wouldn't then the access point mode fails as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the ESP8266 could not obtain the IP address over DHCP (it was enabled in the ESP8266, but the Fritzbox was configured for a limited range only .200 - .209). When setting the IP explicitly:

```
AT+CIPSTA="192.168.92.82","192.168.92.254","255.255.255.0"

OK
```

and then trying to connect, it worked:

```
AT+CWJAP="ap-2","mypassword"
WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP

OK
```

Pinging also works now: :)

```
AT+PING="arduino.stackexchange.com"

+39

OK
```

Answer (score 11):

In my case when I try to connect to my router, I get the following output:

```
AT+CWJAP="myssid","mypassword"
WIFI CONNECTED
+CWJAP:1

FAIL
WIFI DISCONNECT
```

The reason is that the ESP8266 I have is setup with DHCP disabled by default. To enable it you can try the following:

```
AT+CWDHCP=1,1
```

If that works, you will get this message:

```
OK
WIFI GOT IP
```

Comment: Old old old post I know, but pretty sure this is the (more universally) correct answer, rather than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and spent an embarrassing number of hours trying to fix it before coming across this post.

I did a `AT+RESTORE` followed by `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0` since, as expected, my module expected communication on 115200 after the restore.

Then... as if by magic, everything works now...

```
AT+CWJAP="ssis","pwd"
WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP


!
```

I really don't know what was wrong that the `RESTORE` fixed... I must have screwed up the module by experimenting with various commands somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I had many headaches related with this CWJAP:1 error and few others like Ok in return for change IP number command but actually the IP number still the same as before !!! The solution: The AT+RESTORE command to bring the ESP8266 back to the factory defaults... When not logical things happens for unknow reason probably is due to some internal register has dirty values inside and only a AT+RESTORE can normalize them...